# Filter Criteria Search using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am 'newer' to LINQ queries have another one of those questions where I have something going but not sure if this is the most effective way to go about it. In my project, I am working in a real DB, but for a sake of simplicity, here I will condense it down to a simple list of employees:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { Id = 0, firstName = "James", LastName = "Bond", Manager = "M", StartDate = DateTime.Now },
            new Employee { Id = 1, firstName = "Eric", LastName = "Bond", Manager = "M", StartDate = DateTime.Now },
            new Employee { Id = 2, firstName = "Sue", LastName = "Milton", Manager = "Q", StartDate = DateTime.Now },
            new Employee { Id = 3, firstName = "Olivia", LastName = "Milton", Manager = "M", StartDate = DateTime.Now },
            new Employee { Id = 4, firstName = "Alice", LastName = "Raymond", Manager = "M", StartDate = DateTime.Now },
            new Employee { Id = 5, firstName = "James", LastName = "Skywalker", Manager = "M", StartDate = DateTime.Now },
            new Employee { Id = 6, firstName = "Luke", LastName = "Skywalker", Manager = "M", StartDate = DateTime.Now },

        };
```

I have to search in this list based on given criteria.. where criteria is combination of various fields with OR and AND operations with in the fields for example get me all employees where:

- firstName = "James" **OR** "eric" **AND** manager = "Q"
- lastname = "bond" **OR** "Martha"
- firstName = "James" **AND** Lastname = "Bond"
  and so on...

This is going to be a web API call and I have to do this in one method. The other challenge is that each search parameter is 'optional" i.e , they can pass me a list of firstnames and a manager name and ignore the last names parameters etc.  So here is what I started coded:

```
    public IList<Employee> GetFilteredEmployees(IList<String> firstnames = null,
                                                IList<String> lastnames = null,
                                                IList<String> managers = null)
    {
    if (firstnames != null && firstnames.Any())
     {
          foreach (var fn in firstnames)
          {
             employeeByFn = employees.Where(emp => emp.firstName == fn).ToList<Employee>();
          }

      }

     if (lastnames != null && lastnames.Any())
     {
         foreach (var ln in lastnames)
         {
             employeeByLn = employees.Where(emp => emp.LastName == ln).ToList<Employee>();
         }
      }

     ..... // code ellided
    }
```

As you can see, this is getting ugly even with a few search criteria parameters. In my real project, I have up to 16 of those. Also at the end of all these sub-queries, I have to merge my results into one employee list and return that keeping in mind that any of the sub-query result may be null.

I am sure this is not a unique problem and I see similar questions asked before but not exactly the same problem. What would be elegant way of doing this that is also easy to maintain .i.e if they decide to add more search criteria later (say by start Date), I want to be able to easily modify my method to handle that.

Thanks a bunch for looking.

Comment: Why are you constantly taking your data, populating it into a list, and then immediately throwing that list away without using it?  Just stop creating intermediate lists for every single filter you add.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep on adding `Where()` conditions on the same result instead of creating many partial results.

```
public IList<Employee> GetFilteredEmployees(IList<String> firstnames = null,
                                            IList<String> lastnames = null,
                                            IList<String> managers = null)
{
    IQueryable<Employee> result = employees;

    if (firstnames != null)
        result = result.Where(emp => firstnames.Contains(emp.firstName));

    if (lastnames != null)
        result = result.Where(emp => lastnames.Contains(emp.LastName));

    if (managers != null)
        result = result.Where(emp => managers.Contains(emp.Manager));

    ... // code ellided

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Wrong way, If you do this result will contain dublicate entries, distinct will be necessary !

Comment: @DavitTvildiani How exactly is this going to be duplicated? Each aditional `.Where()` returns less than the previous filter not more

Comment: Sorry, no dublicates but your filter is wrong, correct way is  each time start  filtering entire set, not query filtered result from previous query...

because, if "Klara" is not in firstnames and last names contains "bond", your filter will return 0, when it should return something...

Comment: @AlexanderDerck that is not how the OP needs to use `OR`. Sample code only uses `OR` for different values between the same field, which is handled by the `Contains()`

Comment: @DavitTvildiani the way multiple `.Where()` works is by joining more conditions with `AND` which is correct. If I pass a name that doesn't exists on the database, other fields doesn't matter, an empty collection should be returned.

Comment: Wrong!!! It is a chain , and not what you are telling us m that where combines something... 

it is a chain so if First one misses  entire chain misses...

test if you do not believe me

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz If he only needs to keep filtering and never needs lastname = something OR manager = blabla your approach is the easiest and cleanest. But his question is a bit unclear on that part (can't retract downvote because it's been 15 minutes, my apologies).

Comment: @AlexanderDerck You can now

Comment: I know, changed in upvote. Question is just not clear enough to see what is correct approach

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, @ Carlos
Sorry if it was not clear right away:

- within one field, it is always OR
- among various fields it is alwasy AND